# index.php force redirect to custom page

Tags: php, redirect

I need the following help:

Force homepage **index.php** to redirect to **index.php?page=xx**

How?

Comment: You've got tons of options. Send the HTTP Location header. Send one of the HTTP 3** redirect headers, etc.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php/768472#768472)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to redirect the users to the page you wish:

```
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://theos.in/");
```

Comment: `<?  
if(!isset($_GET["page"]){
echo "<script> window.location.href='index.php?page=whatever' </script>;"  ?>}`


this checks to see if the get page variable exists. if it doess not... it will redirect to the page you want but you have to set the page value or it WILL keep looping